# Editable PDF that can’t be altered after completed

Tags: forms, pdf

I am looking to create a legally binding document that can be filled out using an editable PDF document. I then want to send the document and ensure it can’t be edited after

How can I achieve such a result?

David

Comment: Any document can be edited. Would it suffer if any editing would become apparent by a broken or missing digital signature?

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that the filler has a PDF viewer that can open a 256 AES encrypted PDF and is capable of digitally signing the PDF.

Start with a fillable PDF and add a digital signature field.

Set the signature field to lock all fields once signed.

Certify the document using a certificate from a cert store that can be used by your preferred viewer.

When certifying, allow for form filling and signing.

Distribute your form.